# Converting Integer to Binary Using the Math Module (Python)

Tags: python, binary

I am new to programming and learning python and binary. I want to manually convert an integer to binary. I'm trying to do it with a list. I know there are functions that do this and it's not efficient to do it like this. Thanks!

```
import math

binary = []

d = int(raw_input())
stepwise = int(math.log(d, 2))

while d != 0:
    x = int(math.log(d, 2))
    y = 2 ** x
    d -= y

    if stepwise == x:
        binary.append("1")
    else:
        binary.append("0")

    stepwise -= 1

print binary
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: There's a standard library function for converting integers to binary strings. Just use [`bin()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say that you are trying to convert the integer 'manually' to binary, I am assuming that you are not willing to use the `bin()` function. Here is something you can try.

```
from math import*
x= int(raw_input('Enter the decimal number'))
n=[]
while x>1:
    y=int(x%2)
    n=n+[y]
    x=floor(x/2.0)
if x==1:
    n=n+[1]
elif x==0:
    n=n+[0]
size=len(n)
print 'binary equivalent =',
y=-1
while y>=-size:
    print n[y],
    y=y-1
print ''
```

Comment: Is this what you asked?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was trying to do. Thanks!